# Invalid parameter for estimator Pipeline (SVR)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, pipeline

I have a data set with 100 columns of continuous features, and a continuous label, and I want to run SVR; extracting features of relevance, tuning hyper parameters, and then cross-validating my model that is fit to my data.

I wrote this code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scaled_df, target, test_size=0.2)
    
cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)

# define the pipeline to evaluate
model = SVR()
fs = SelectKBest(score_func=mutual_info_regression)
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('sel',fs), ('svr', model)])

# define the grid
grid = dict()

#How many features to try
grid['estimator__sel__k'] = [i for i in range(1, X_train.shape[1]+1)]


# define the grid search
#search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, grid, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=-1, cv=cv)
search = GridSearchCV(
        pipeline,
#        estimator=SVR(kernel='rbf'),
        param_grid={
            'estimator__svr__C': [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000],
            'estimator__svr__epsilon': [0.0001, 0.0005,  0.001, 0.005,  0.01, 0.05, 1, 5, 10],
            'estimator__svr__gamma': [0.0001, 0.0005,  0.001, 0.005,  0.01, 0.05, 1, 5, 10]
        },
        scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
        verbose=1,
        n_jobs=-1)

for param in search.get_params().keys():
    print(param)

# perform the search
results = search.fit(X_train, y_train)

# summarize best
print('Best MAE: %.3f' % results.best_score_)
print('Best Config: %s' % results.best_params_)

# summarize all
means = results.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
params = results.cv_results_['params']
for mean, param in zip(means, params):
    print(">%.3f with: %r" % (mean, param))
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter estimator for estimator Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('sel',
                 SelectKBest(k=10,
                             score_func=<function mutual_info_regression at 0x7fd2ff649cb0>)),
                ('svr',
                 SVR(C=1.0, cache_size=200, coef0=0.0, degree=3, epsilon=0.1,
                     gamma='scale', kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, shrinking=True,
                     tol=0.001, verbose=False))],
         verbose=False). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

When I print `estimator.get_params().keys()`, as suggested in the error message, I get:

```
cv
error_score
estimator__memory
estimator__steps
estimator__verbose
estimator__sel
estimator__svr
estimator__sel__k
estimator__sel__score_func
estimator__svr__C
estimator__svr__cache_size
estimator__svr__coef0
estimator__svr__degree
estimator__svr__epsilon
estimator__svr__gamma
estimator__svr__kernel
estimator__svr__max_iter
estimator__svr__shrinking
estimator__svr__tol
estimator__svr__verbose
estimator
iid
n_jobs
param_grid
pre_dispatch
refit
return_train_score
scoring
verbose
Fitting 5 folds for each of 405 candidates, totalling 2025 fits
```

But when I change the line:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('sel',fs), ('svr', model)])
```

to:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('estimator__sel',fs), ('estimator__svr', model)])
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Estimator names must not contain __: got ['estimator__sel', 'estimator__svr']
```

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong, i.e. how do I combine the pipeline/feature selection step into the GridSearchCV?

As a side note, if I comment out `pipeline` in the GridSearchCV, and uncomment `estimator=SVR(kernal='rbf')`, the cell runs without issue, but in that case, I presume I am not incorporating the feature selection in, as it's not called anywhere. I have seen some previous SO questions, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647555/invalid-parameter-loss-for-estimator-svr), but they don't seem to answer this specific question.

Is there a cleaner way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error message is about the `pipeline` parameters, not the `search` parameters, and indicates that your `param_grid` is bad, not the pipeline step names.  Running `pipeline.get_params().keys()` should show you the right parameter names.  Your grid should be:

```py
        param_grid={
            'svr__C': [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000],
            'svr__epsilon': [0.0001, 0.0005,  0.001, 0.005,  0.01, 0.05, 1, 5, 10],
            'svr__gamma': [0.0001, 0.0005,  0.001, 0.005,  0.01, 0.05, 1, 5, 10]
        },
```

I don't know how substituting the plain SVR for the pipeline runs; your parameter grid doesn't specify the right things there either...

Comment: Thanks. When I change the param_grid to your code, it runs (with a really bad Spearman between y_pred and y_test). That's fine if that's really the case, but I wanted to check that wasn't because of an improperly made model. I don't understand  'I don't know how substituting the plain SVR for the pipeline runs; your parameter grid doesn't specify the right things there either...'. Are you saying this code should not run? I have the code in a file by itself just with some data read in before it, and when I print `y_pred = results.predict(X_test); print y_pred[0:10]`, it prints 10 predictions.

Comment: @Slowat_Kela I was referring to your "side note" paragraph.  If `estimator=SVR(...)`, then having `estimator__svr__C` in the `param_grid` should fail with the same error as you originally reported; in this version, the parameter name should be just `C`.

Comment: Oh sorry that's my fault, I wasn't clear. I had `estimator=SVR(...)` in, when I just had C, epsilon and gamma in param grid sorry (not the `estimator__svr_C`). Sorry I wasn't clear, I meant that I can get this piece of code generally to run if I just use plain SVR, but not if I swap it over to a pipeline.